# how to write pdf file in browser using servlet?

Tags: java, pdf, servlets, response, fileoutputstream

here the below code trying to write pdf file from local machine to browser, but here doesn't write file to browser

```
String pdfFileName = "hello1.pdf";
            String contextPath = "";
                    contextPath = "/home/admin/Desktop/";
            File pdfFile = new File(contextPath + pdfFileName);
                    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(pdfFile);
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + pdfFileName);
            response.setContentLength((int) pdfFile.length());      
            OutputStream responseOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
                    System.out.println("fileInputstream length : " + fileInputStream.available());
            int length;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            while ((length = fileInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                responseOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
                    System.out.println(" outputstream length : " + responseOutputStream.toString());
                    fileInputStream.close();
                    responseOutputStream.flush();
                    responseOutputStream.close();
```

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what happens when you hit your servlet with a request?  Is _anything_ returned back?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen here the problem is i'm trying to open response data in browser but it's failed

Comment: I suspect that the PDF file is being written incorrectly, and your browser is choking on it when it tries to open it.

Comment: Please verify that this PDF file has not been corrupted.  Can you open it on your server, or download it by some other means and open it?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen File not corrupted its open manually

Comment: Please store the PDF as received by the browser and compare it to the original. In what way do they differ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code statement:

```
response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + pdfFileName);
```

change"attachment" to "inline", like below :

```
response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + pdfFileName);
```

Then pdf file will open automatically